# Convert String into List

Tags: java

I have List which I use to convert into String:

```
    private String convertList(List<String> list)
    {
        String listString = "";

        for (String s : list)
        {
            listString += s + ",";
        }
        return listString;
    }
```

But I also want to implement the same operation backwards. I want to generate List from String using `,` as delimiter. How this can be implemented?

Comment: There is no `LinkedHashMap` in the given code.

Comment: you mean LinkedList?

Comment: I mean List. Please see the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `split` to generate an array of `String` tokens, and `Arrays.asList` to generate the `List` :

```
List<String> theList = Arrays.asList(bigString.split(","));
```

Comment: Note, this will produce an unmodifiable List. You cannot add elements to or remove elements from this List. If you need it to be modifiable you will need to do:

`List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(listString.split(",")));`